# Rails 3 model join limit to one result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Hi have 3 models: keyword, site, result

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results
  has_many :sites, through: :results
end

class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :results
  has_many :keywords, through: :results
end

class Result < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :site
  belongs_to :keyword
end
```

On the sites_controller I am trying to show a list of all keywords along with the latest result for that keyword and site.

This join give me the keyword with all results, how can i limit it to just the most recent result for each keyword?

```
@keywords = Keyword.joins(:results).where("results.site_id = ?", @site.id).includes(:results).order('keywords.created_at ASC').load
```

Answer (score 0):

Reversing the `created_at` order and adding a limit of 1 should solve your problem:

```
Keyword.joins(:results).where("results.site_id = ?", @site.id).includes(:results).order("keywords.created_at DESC").limit(1)
```

Comment: I'm trying to limit the results to 1 not the keywords or the keyword order